# How to execute an MQL4 program in a server?

Tags: php, webserver, server, mql4, mql5

I have implemented an expert advisor using the MQL4 language to be executed in MetaTrader.

Now, if I need to execute it, I always need to run MetaTrader and attach my EA program to a live currency pair graph in it.

I want to know whether there is **a method to execute MQL4 scripts in servers** so that I do not need to keep my computer always on. I googled this question, but I could not find an appropriate answer to it.

I found there is a way to transfer data from MetaTrader to the web server (MQL to PHP) but I have no idea whether it is useful to solve my question (http://mql4-php.iinuu.eu/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there are few DLL-based methods to transfer "just" DATA

ZeroMQ DLL for socket based messaging approaches.

Windows raw-sockets' for a low-level socket programming.

A few other, DLL-based, tools for passing data to/from remote or parallel processes.

### No, there are no known methods to run MQL4-CODE on a server

Each MQL4 source-code is first compiled into an **`.EX4`** file. Such "executable" files are loaded and executed in a similarly proprietary piece of software -- in a <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd>. So far, there are no known server-process implementations for this functionality and MetaQuotes, Inc., does not either sell or develop any visible effort to release any such software. Due to legal reasons, there would hardly be any open source programmes, that would work in this direction, as any similar efforts have started legal consequences initiated in a name of protecting the intellectual property in any case, where a non-published nature of the data-transfers and/or operations distributed among MetaTrader4 Terminal [localhost-side] and/or MetaTrader4 Server [broker-side] programmes was to be touched or otherwise analysed and/or re-engineered.

### But, there is a way to solve your wish

There is a common practice to operate the localhost-side piece of software -- the <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd> -- hosted on a remote machine, that is being kept running in a 24/7/365-style in a professional DataCentre.

Using this kind of approach, your **`MQL4`**-code is still being run in a native mode inside a <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd> software process, however, the machine ( the Windows O/S based machine ) is virtualised into a VM and hosted in a DataCentre infrastructure.

There are nevertheless some steps & measures needed so as to protect your privacy and your intellectual property rights once thinking about the VM/hosted mode of operations of your EA/script.

Applying this mode of operations will allow you to connect from your localhost to the DataCenter just in a time when you want to visually check and/or manually correct and/or modify your all-the-time-running code in a <kbd>MetaTrader4 Terminal</kbd> in a non-stop mode.

Answer (score 0):

Noting on the following requirement:

> "I want to know whether there is a method to execute MQL4 scripts in
>   servers so that **I do not need to keep my computer always on**."

You can subscribe to VPS (Virtual Private Server) services where you can attach your EA (.ex4) files to. Basically, it acts as a server-hosting (but a really small one, just enough to run your MT4 Terminal).

There are many VPS offerings. Just google `Metatrader4 VPS`.
In fact, Metaquotes itself also offers this service, straight off your MT4. Once you subscribe to that service and attach your .EX4, you can then switch off your PC and the EA will still be running on the VPS.
You can find details here [Link](http://www.metaquotes.net/en/metatrader4/news/4273).

Answer (score 0):

Most brokers nowadays offer **`Virtual Private Server`** aka **`VPS`** solutions, which aims to reduce the latency & slippage on your trades. This means that your system will be "virtually" closer to the brokers services, reducing the time it takes for pricing and execution orders to travel from your `VPS` to the brokers servers.

Comment: You might want to know, that the initial question is a bit dual-sworded. First, MetaTrader Server is a broker-side server facility, that can operate with add-on plugin-code, while this is nothing open to client-side code deployment. Next, VPS offerings are most commonly offerend as an option, whereas the broker company typically does not want to be legally responsible for any damages ( +most VPS offerings are "almost" free of charge, which means zero-guarrantee of anythin ). As a rule of thumb, first check RTT-latency to realise, whether VPS is anywhere near the server colocation ( not sure )

Comment: Have seen VPS-providers, that started VM-operating system patching with reboot in the middle of the week, hanging all EA-operations with just showing you ex-post a **Press [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Del] to log on** *"welcome screen"*

Comment: Have seen brokers with "superior **VPS offerings" where L3-RTT-latencies were above 340 ms (!!!)**. Next is to test the Broker Server-Farm capabilities, L3-RTT-latency does not say anything about a Broker-side processing latencies.... Use **SONAR** & **TAMARA** telemetry-tools to measure these latencies in realtime. Hardly could recommend anything better than a prior proof of QoS ... try-before-buy. ( Java updates + expired certificates blocked access, etc, etc ).